# plotly sankey graph data formatting

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, sankey-diagram

plotly library has some nice sankey diagrams
https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/

but the data requires you to pass indexes of the source/target pairs.

```py
    link = dict(
      source = [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3], # indices correspond to labels, eg A1, A2, A1, B1, ...
      target = [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5],
```

I was wondering if there's an API to simply pass a named list of these pairs?

```
links = [
    {'source': 'start', 'target': 'A', 'value': 2},
    {'source': 'A', 'target': 'B', 'value': 2},
...
]
```

this is more inline with how [bokeh/holoviews](https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Sankey.html)
expects data (but that sankey doesn't work with self-loops)

and also this [pysankey widget](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ricklupton/ipysankeywidget/blob/master/examples/Simple%20example.ipynb)

so i can closer map to my dataframe without processing everything?

or, is there a nice pythonic way to convert this in a one liner :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- the structure is clearly a **pandas** dataframe constructor format
- create a dataframe from it, plus the key series of the nodes
- from this it's simple to construct a Sankey plot from it

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

links = [
    {'source': 'start', 'target': 'A', 'value': 2},
    {'source': 'A', 'target': 'B', 'value': 1},
    {'source': 'A', 'target':'C', 'value':.5}

]

df = pd.DataFrame(links)
nodes = np.unique(df[["source","target"]], axis=None)
nodes = pd.Series(index=nodes, data=range(len(nodes)))

go.Figure(
    go.Sankey(
        node={"label": nodes.index},
        link={
            "source": nodes.loc[df["source"]],
            "target": nodes.loc[df["target"]],
            "value": df["value"],
        },
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: nice! so you'd prefer `nodes = np.unique(df.loc[:,["source","target"]].values.ravel())` to something like a list comprehension on the keys? it's a bit hard to read for me with the `[:,` and `ravel` ... but i don't have a simpler alternative.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html would do same thing.  I've been working with pandas and numpy for quite sometime so am comfortable with the idioms... :-)  maybe this is more readable `np.unique(df[["source","target"]].values.flatten())` for readability

Comment: `nodes = np.unique(df[["source","target"]], axis=None)` is even more succinct ...

Comment: much nicer, thanks! do you want to edit your answer? i've accepted anyway