# Multistep Sankey Graph from Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, sankey-diagram

I have a dataframe with the following structure

| INDEX | ANO | DISTRITO | CONCELHO | NCCO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2013.0 | Aveiro | Albergaria-a-Velha | 98 |
| 1 | 2013.0 | Aveiro | Albergaria-a-velha | 1 |
| 2 | 2013.0 | Aveiro | Anadia | 41 |

The full dataset can be found [**here**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vostpt/ICNF_DATA/main/heatmap_full.csv)

This data set ranges from 2013 to 2022 (`ANO`), and includes 18 different districts (`DISTRITO`), 278 different counties (`CONCELHO`) and the number of forest fires per `CONCELHO` (`NCCO´)

I'm able to produce a one step Sankey graph with this code, that I adapted from [here](https://coderzcolumn.com/tutorials/data-science/how-to-plot-sankey-diagram-in-python-jupyter-notebook-holoviews-and-plotly)

```
df = pd.read_csv('heatmap_full.csv') #generated by ingestor.py

all_nodes = df.ANO.values.tolist() + df.DISTRITO.values.tolist() 
source_indices = [all_nodes.index(ANO) for ANO in df.ANO]
target_indices = [all_nodes.index(DISTRITO) for DISTRITO in df.DISTRITO]

colors = px.colors.qualitative.D3
node_colors = [np.random.choice(colors) for node in all_nodes]

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    # Define nodes
    node = dict(
    pad = 20,
    thickness = 20,
    line = dict(color = "black", width = 1.0),
    label =  all_nodes,
    color =  node_colors,
    ),

    # Add links
    link = dict(
      source =  source_indices,
      target =  target_indices,
      value =  df.NCCO,
))])

fig.update_layout(title_text="FOREST FIRES IN PORTUGAL",
                height = 900,
                width=1200,
                font_size=18)
fig.show()
```

[image: One Step Sankey]

**My Problem/Question**

I would like to have a step after `DISTRITO` for `CONCELHO` appearing in the Sankey graph, but I can't figure it out.

Can I add a new trace to the figure? Do I need to treat my original dataset in another way?

**Any help would be much appreciated**

*Disclosure* This is not meant for commercial use.

Comment: Not directly the question, but I doubt a Sankey diagram is the best representation for this type of data. A heatmap or grouped bars would probably be much more informative.

Comment: @mozway appreciate the comment, but this will be part of a larger dashboard that allows users to visualise the datasets in several formats, including heatmaps.

Answer (score 1):

- reusing this answer to build a Sankey Diagram [plotly sankey graph data formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69463804/plotly-sankey-graph-data-formatting/69464558#69464558)
- build data frame of source and target values.  Note two data cleanups

  1. there are duplicate *CONCELHO* due to capitalisation
  2. there are same values in *CONCELHO* and *DISTRITO*.  modify so that no circular items in sankey
- as per comments there really are too many nodes to represent in a sankey

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df_in = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vostpt/ICNF_DATA/main/heatmap_full.csv")

# too much data
df_in = df_in.sample(100)

# cleanup where same values exist in two columns
df_in["CONCELHO"] = np.where(df_in["DISTRITO"]==df_in["CONCELHO"], df_in["CONCELHO"]+"_c", df_in["CONCELHO"])
# deal with some duplicates names across source and target...
df_in["CONCELHO"] = df_in["CONCELHO"].str.capitalize()
df = df_in.groupby(["ANO","DISTRITO"], as_index=False)["NCCO"].sum().rename(columns={"ANO":"source","DISTRITO":"target","NCCO":"value"})
df["source"] = df["source"].astype(int).astype(str)

df = pd.concat([df, df_in.groupby(["DISTRITO","CONCELHO"], as_index=False)["NCCO"].sum().rename(columns={"DISTRITO":"source","CONCELHO":"target", "NCCO":"value"})])

nodes = np.unique(df[["source","target"]], axis=None)
nodes = pd.Series(index=nodes, data=range(len(nodes)))

go.Figure(
    go.Sankey(
        node={"label": nodes.index},
        link={
            "source": nodes.loc[df["source"]],
            "target": nodes.loc[df["target"]],
            "value": df["value"],
        },
    )
)
```

[image]